# Laravel eloquent select all users from arrays of emails and phone numbers

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build an Eloquent query using an array of email addresses and an array of phone numbers that returns all users that match either one of the phone numbers or one of the email addresses. Here are the methods I've attempted:

Passing a function to `where`:

```
public function findFromContacts($emailAddresses = array(), $phoneNumbers = array()) {
    return AppUser::where(function($query) use($emailAddresses, $phoneNumbers) {
        foreach($emailAddresses as $emailAddress) {
            $query->orWhere('email', $emailAddress);
        }
        foreach($phoneNumbers as $phoneNumber) {
            $query->orWhere('phone', $phoneNumber);
        }
    })->get();
}
```

Appending `whereOr` clauses with `array_reduce`:

```
public function findFromContacts($emailAddresses = array(), $phoneNumbers = array()) {
    $query = AppUser::query();
    $queryWithEmailAddresses = array_reduce($emailAddresses, function ($query, $emailAddress) {
        return $query->orWhere('email', $emailAddress);
    }, $query);
    $queryWithPhoneNumbers = array_reduce($phoneNumbers, function ($query, $phoneNumber) {
        return $query->orWhere('phone', $phoneNumber);
    }, $queryWithEmailAddresses);
    return $queryWithPhoneNumbers->get();
}
```

Both of these return every entry in the table.

Currently, the only method I've found that works is to query the database once for every email and every phone number which isn't ideal.

Comment: why not use "whereIn" and give that your arrays, much simpler

Comment: @ATechGuy I was unaware of that method. It looks like just what I need. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: done and done, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using "whereIn" it will look for only the stuff you want and should do the trick.

```
public function findFromContacts($emailAddresses = array(), $phoneNumbers = array()) {
    return AppUser::whereIn('email', $emailAddresses)
        ->orWhereIn('phone', $phoneNumbers)
        ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as you need an or of the two.

```
  $query->where(function($query1){
                  $query1->orWhereIn('email',$emailAddresses)
                  ->orWhereIn('phone',$phoneNumber);
})
```